# How to use Interop.Outlook to change print options

Tags: c#, outlook

I would like to use the Interop.Outlook API to dynamically change the Print Options in outlook. For example I would like to change the Memo Style Page Setup to use Letter Size paper with a Landscape Orientation. How can I go about doing this?

I have looked at the Outlook documentation and I have not been able to find how to do this. Is this something that can only be done using the registry?

If so, would anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Object Model provides no way to control any print settings. MailItem.PrintOut is all you get.

You might want to export the message (MailItem.saveAs), then import it in Word and use Word Object Model to print.

Comment: I should note though, I would like to print an MSG file using the print Memo Style and Table Style options but with different paper sizes. Can I still do this using Word?