# Interop.Outlook Print to File (PDF)?

Tags: html, pdf, outlook, office-interop

There are many libraries out there which purport to transform HTML to PDF.  All that I've looked at have there limitations.  We don't want to spend any money on this so wanted to know if it is possible to print to file in PDF format without all the pop ups that Outlook would normally produce.  We are using Outlook 2013 with Exchange.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456997/how-to-use-interop-outlook-to-change-print-options) suggests that the answer it NO.  But [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456997/how-to-use-interop-outlook-to-change-print-options) suggests that it might be done.  I'm looking for a clear path to achieve my goal.

To complicate things, I am using the Mail.Display function to allow the user to modify the email before sending.  They can add attachments if they want also.  Once they select the Send option, I want to capture the email that was sent and produce a PDF which will be stored in a data store for easy retrieval by anyone who accesses the customer account.  Here is where I run into difficulty.  The Mail object is not available after returning from the Display function.  How can I get the sent email and process it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Interop.Outlook to change print options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456997/how-to-use-interop-outlook-to-change-print-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. So, you can use the Word object model to get the job done. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

The [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.exportasfixedformat.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Document class saves the document in PDF or XPS format.

Comment: I am grateful for your helpful answer.  I see light at the end of the tunnel.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I do have a question though, when the user is presented with the email that they can modify, how do I know if they sent it or cancelled?  After the return from Outlook's Mail.Display(Model), where is this information kept?

Comment: You need to handle item events such as [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867634(v=office.15).aspx), [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868010(v=office.15).aspx) and etc.